# Convert MongoDB field type on import

Tags: json, mongodb, import, mongoimport

I have over 5 million JSON objects stored in hundreds of text files that I am going to import into a Mongo Database. I created a windows batch file to iterate over the directories the files are stored in and import them using 'mongoimport'. This works as expected, but one of the fields in the JSON object is a float value that was stored as a string for some reason.

Is there anyway to convert his field type while importing the data? I have tried converting the field to a number afterwards, but it is extremely slow.

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "user": "user1",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "time": "111111111111"
}
```

Comment: Do you checked if it is something about the locale?, ex comma vs dot representation. Do you can post a JSON as example, using pastebin or similar?

Comment: It is just a basic JSON object with a time property that is in a string. The time is in ms since Epoch. { time:"111111111" }

Comment: Well, in this case you are sending literaly a string, mongo manage the datetimes out of simple JSON standar, I thinks the easy way is import all the data and run an script chaning the datatype.

Comment: I agree. From the comment it looks like you're sending a string. Can you edit the question to include a sample JSON object?

Comment: The JSON object has a string. I have imported it previously and then ran a script to change the data type, but changing the data type took 10-20x longer than importing the data, so I was hoping there was some way to change the data type on import.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, if you want to convert string to int for `field` in python and pymongo lib:

```
client = MongoClient("some_url")
db = client["db"]
collection = db["name_of_collection"]
path_to_data = 'data.json'
with open(path_data) as file:
    file_data = json.load(file)
                
    if isinstance(file_data, list):
        for document in file_data:
            document["field"] = int(document["field"])
        collection.insert_many(file_data)
```